# Hyperledger composer upgrade business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Let's say I have a business network v1.0.0 which has a Participant with the following model:

```
participant Member identified by memberId {
   o String memberId
   o String firstName
}
```

After deploying the network I create a Member.

Later I want to add a field to the Member model. E.g.

```
participant Member identified by memberId {
   o String memberId
   o String firstName
   o String lastName
}
```

So I create new network and upgrade the previous one:

```
composer network upgrade -c peeradmin@hlfv1 -n example-netowrk -V 2.0.0
```

What happens to the member I created before? Is it deleted? How can I keep that in the system and continue to use it and update it's information by only adding *lastName*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evolution of model definitions is described in the documentation here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/model-compatibility and should answer your question.

Comment: and there is some more information in the Knowledge Wiki: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#migration

Answer (score 0):

when you change the model, your api will change as well to reflect the changes. Your data won't disappear, it can't as it's on the ledger, but it won't have the new fields you added.

Once your new model is deployed you can then issue a GET request to that asset, this gives you all the existing data, you populate the new field with whatever you need and issue a PUT request on that asset. This will now give you an old asset with the new data.

Of course, I suggest you think carefully how you change existing assets. I am thinking here of a policy which says you should not rename anything, you should not delete anything. all you should do is add new properties. If you start messing around with renaming and deleting, this is bound to cause issue, especially in a production environment.